# Rate of uniform approximation by piecewise constant functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, na.numerical-analysis, approximation-theory

**Definitions and Notation:**

Fix a positive constant $M>0$ with positive integers $m,n$ and the standard orthonormal basis $e_1,\dots,e_n$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

For every positive integer $N$, define the class $\mathcal{H}^{(m,n,N)}$ of *piecewise constant functions* of the form

$$
\sum_{j=1}^N\, k_j\cdot \prod_{i=1}^n I_{[a_{i,j},b_{i,j}]}\big(\langle x,e_i\rangle\big),
$$
where $k_1,\dots,k_N\in \mathbb{R}^m$.

---

**Question:**

1. At what rate can $\mathcal{H}^{(m,n,N)}$ approximate continuous functions? I am looking for a rate $r>0$ such that for every sufficiently large $N$, and for every uniformly continuous $f:[-M,M]^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ with modulus of continuity $\omega$,
   $$
   \inf_{h\in \mathcal{H}^{(m,n,N)}}\, \sup_{x\in [-M,M]^n}\, \|h(x)-f(x)\|_2 < cN^{-r}
   $$
   where $c$ may depend on $M,m,n,\omega$ but is independent of $f$ and $N$.
2. Can we achieve a better rate if $f \in C^k(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)$ and we know it's [modulus of smoothness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulus_of_smoothness)?

Comment: I think the key example is $m=1$, $f= w \sum \langle x,e_i \rangle$, with a minimum error achieved by dividing the big cube into smaller cubes all of the same size. If so, the limiting error is $2MN^{-1/n}nw$ and the desired rate is $r=1/n$.

Comment: More generally, for a uniformly continuous $f$ with mod. of c. $\omega$, the distance from $f$ to $H^{(m,n,N)}$ should be around  $\omega(MN^{-1/n}n^{1/2})$ (taking the locally constant function equal to $f$ in the center of each of $N$ cubes of equal size, and pretending $N$ is a power of $n$). 

So I’d say to get a distance $cN^{-r}$ from $H^{(m,n,N)}$ you need $f$ to be  Hoelder of exponent $rn$. So $r=1/n$ should be ok, but for $f$ Lipschitz.

Comment: Matt and Pietro; Do you know of a reference?

Comment: @PietroMajer So, as stated, the problem is only about packing numbers?

Comment: I don’t know a reference — but why define piecewise constancy with box-shaped pieces?

Comment: @MattF. Ah, since the question stems from trying to mathematically understand why regression trees (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree_learning) do well *(I was playing with some code on my free time and then I became curious)*.

Comment: @PietroMajer Still, can we do better if we know the function's modulus of smoothness (I've updated the question).

Comment: It seems the quantity you define on the LHS, (that is the point-set distance from $f$ to the space  $H^{m,n,N}$) is itself a sort  of "mean modulus of continuity", something weaker than the usual (uniform) modulus of continuity: it could actually be $cN^{-r}$ even if $f$ is not Hoelder, e.g. if it has a very thin, non Hoelder cuspid at a single point $x_0$ (then the cubes of the approximating h have to be very small around $x_0$, a lot of them,  but that is possible if elsewhere f is more flat so that less cubes are needed)

Comment: @PietroMajer I guess it reduces to bounding the Assouad dimension of $f([-M,M]^n)$ then?